# How do I set up htaccess rewrite rules for exact url with parameters and without

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following three url's

```
https://mycurrentsite.com/product/ ==> https://mynewsite.com/product

https://mycurrentsite.com/product/caps ==> https://mynewsite.com/tops

https://mycurrentsite.com/product/?typeofcaps=fliptop ==> https://mynewsite.com/fasteners
```

each of these needs a redirect rule

This is how I set up my redirect rules

```
RewriteEngine on 
  
RewriteRule ^product/.?$ https://www.mynewsite.com/en/product/fasteners [QSD,R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^product/.*$ https://www.mynewsite.com/en/product/tops [QSD,R=301,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^product/$ https://www.mynewsite.com/en/product [R=301,L,NC]
 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewsite.com/en/home [QSD,R=302,L,NC]
```

the first 2 rules work perfectly. the one I am having difficulty with is when I put in the following url

https://mycurrentsite.com/product/
It keeps redirecting to https://www.mynewsite.com/en/product/fasteners
How do I redirect to https://www.mynewsite.com/en/product

Comment: `^product/.?$` - you allowed for one arbitrary optional character after the slash here, so of course `product/` matches that pattern. If you want to check on query string contents, then you need to use a RewriteCond to do that.

Comment: okay, thank you. i will review the docs on how to set this up

Comment: "the first 2 rules work perfectly" - Although they don't do what you've outlined in the preceding examples?

Comment: I assume you mean because my example, left out the /en/product?

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Not just `/en/product`, but also `fasteners`? `/product/` and `/product/<any-char>` is redirected to `/en/product/fasteners` by the first rule. (?) In your example `caps`, should be redirected to `tops`. However, your second rule redirects `<everything-else>` to `tops`?

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Is this now resolved or are you still after a solution?